# Prolog: compilation failed

Tags: compiler-errors, prolog

I am new to prolog so please excuse me if its a simple to fix.
First part of code before "member" work without any errors of compiling.
After that i dont know instructions are correctly wrote or not. When i try added instructions "who can be together or not", i have  error of compiling.

```
solve(Solve):-
  Solve = [room(X, Y, Z, W)],
  man(X), man(Y), man(Z), man(W), unique([X, Y, Z, W]).

unique([]):-!.
unique([Head|Tail]):-
   member(Head, Tail), !, fail;
   unique(Tail).

man(andrey).
man(boris).
man(kostya).
man(vasya).
man(dima).
man(yura).
man(fedya).
man(grisha).


member(room(andrey, _, _, _), Solve),
member(room(vasya, _, _, _), Solve),
member(room(boris, kostya, _, _), Solve),
member(room(dima, yura, _, _), Solve),
member(room(fedya, dima, grisha, _), Solve),
member(room(fedya, dima, kostya, _), Solve),
member(room(yura, boris, _, _), Solve),
member(room(yura, fedya, _, _), Solve),
member(room(yura, grisha, kostya, _), Solve),
not(member(room(kostya, vasya, _, _), Solve)),
not(member(room(grisha, boris, kostya, _), Solve)),
not(member(room(grisha, andrey, _, _), Solve)),
not(member(room(grisha, vasya, _, _), Solve)),
not(member(room(yura, andrey, _, _), Solve)),
not(member(room(yura, vasya, _, _), Solve)).
```

However, when i try to compile it i get error:

- prog.pl:22-37: fatal error: redefining control construct (',')/2

Comment: First, there are potential nameclashes with built–in predicates like `member/2` and/or `not/2`.

Comment: Look at the line `member(room(andrey, _, _, _), Solve),` ! It ends with `,` not `.` .

Comment: As a consequence of these goals being on the same level as all other *clauses*, Prolog thinks you are trying to define a predicate `(,)/2` which probably is not quite what you want... oh, and by way, said predicate (conjunctionj is already defined.

Comment: This mistake is quite common and not so easy to find. Bad!

Comment: I added `.` after each of the functions `member` and `not member` but now i have error `redefining built-in predicate member/2`

Comment: This is understandable, as `member/2` **is** built–in and thus already defined...

Comment: So, what should a single of these lines mean (in plain English)? And what's with this variable `Solve`?

Comment: Actually, defining a predicate `not/1` does not make much sense to me... predefined predicate `(\+)/2` provides negation as finite failure, but don't try to redefine that one, too;)

Comment: `member` - who can be in one room; 
`not member` - who can`t;
 if I understood correctly that you are asking

Comment: I think I get that... but why then do you need to define both the negatve and the positive cases. what if these are not consistent? what about 'i dont know' cases?

Comment: For example, Andrey can be in a room with anyone, while the Yura does not want to be with him. I must take into account the wishes of Andrey and Yura at the same time, because of this i define both of cases

Answer (score 1):

First problem is that you have defined facts which terminate with comma as @Repeat already mentioned above.

Second this program is not correct where you call unique predicate with an array which is instantiated with names. For example it can look like unique([andrey,andrey,andrey,andrey]) and what happends next is that unique is being called which calls `member` with `(Head = andrey)`which will fail because it can't find a `member(andrey)` but it can find `member(room(,,,,))` so here you are missing `room`. If you want that all of `member` and `not(member(,,,))`facts must succeed then you need to create a new rule and put all these `facts` in that rule.

Comment: for the second you mean i should add `not(member(room(grisha, grisha, grisha, grisha), Solve)),` for everyone and this one `member(room(,,,,))`?

Comment: Look you are calling `Unique` predicate with a list of names like this: `Uniques([X,Y,Z,W]) ` and all these variables are instantiated with some name(X = andrey,Y=andrey,Z=andrey,W = andrey). So in unique rule prolog see it like this `unique(andrey|Tail = Y,Z,W)` and at this point you call `member(Head =andrey,Tail)` which will not succeed because there is nothing like `member(andrey,Tail)`. You should change it to `unique([H|Tail]) :- member(room(H,_,_,_),Tail), unique(Tail).` btw i am not sure what are you trying to do if you tell me exactly what you want then i will try toh hel you.:-)